# How to get (some) filenames within a directory efficiently

Tags: java, file-listing

I have a directory with 20M+ files in it. If I try

```
folder.list();
```

It'll take me about 5~10min to get the file (sometimes even more). I don't need all file names, just a handful everytime.

In Linux if I try:

- `ls -l | head -n 100`: it'll take forever
- `ls -f | head -n 100`: response is obtained in a few seconds.

So I can list files quickly if I use `ProcessBuilder` and run something like `ls -f | head -n 100`

Is there a native way for listing a fixed number of files within a directory without requiring to using `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: well, you can use JNI to implement your own native code to access the FS directly (BTW, what file system are you using in this case?), but ProcessBuilder can be way easier in this case. 20M files in a directory is really not a usual situation, although, you're not wrong to expect a decent performance in this case.

Comment: @Leo `ProcessBuilder` is easy, but I don't want to write a `Java` program that only runs on Linux. maybe one day we decide to throw the HD into a Windows Server or etc...

Comment: well, you can try NIO2 support in Java for file system, maybe it's fater -- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is way using [Java NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) and the class [`DirectoryStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html). This class implements a lazy iterable over the entries of a directory. You can obtain an instance of `DirectoryStream<Path>` using [`Files.newDirectoryStream(path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-) (and you can obtain an instance of `Path` with the static factories [`Paths.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.net.URI-)).

If you are using Java 8, an even simpler solution would be to use [`Files.list()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-):

> Return a lazily populated `Stream`, the elements of which are the entries in the directory. The listing is not recursive.

You could then have

```
List<String> fileNames = Files.list(path)
                              .map(Path::getFileName)
                              .map(Path::toString)
                              .limit(100)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

to retrieve the 100 file names of the given `path`.

Comment: nice, didn't know about NIO.2 , But we definitely have to upgrade our system to start using Java-8.

Answer (score 1):

you could try if the java7 nio file operations are faster for you. they were a big improvement in one case where i used them: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html